# Ios "stop" button to correspond with "play" and "pause"

Tags: ios, graphics

In my IOS app, I play short snippets of audio. I want to give the user the option to stop what is playing, in the sense of abandoning it and moving on. So it's not really a pause. However, I find no system "stop" button, except for the "X". I was thinking more of the standard square block. Do I have to make my own?

Comment: It's worth asking if there really is any difference between pause and stop in your app, from the user's perspective. What app behavior differs between the two, and is that something a user is likely to expect? That there is no such button built into the OS should probably make you pause and ask yourself if iOS users are going to expect some kind of "stop" behavior that's not what they normally get with "pause" behavior. Will your user interface be sufficiently obvious to those who don't normally see stop buttons?

Comment: Yeah, I've asked myself that question and yeah, I think there's a difference between "stop" and "pause". But I'll look into implementing  "pause". I'm using Nuance, and their speech API.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, iOS provides no such icon to my knowledge.  The icon should be trivially simple to create, seeing as it is simply that square block.